# Date Formatter in Swift is not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, date-format

I am working with dates in Swift. I have to convert from String to Date but some weird stuff is happening. When I run my code on a simulator and pass my date string to formatter, it returns nil. But when I run my code on a physical device it works perfectly.

```
class ChatViewController: MessagesViewController {
    
    var uid: String
    var isNewConversations:Bool
    private var messages = [Message]()
    private var selfSender: Sender?
    var senderUid: String
    var conversation_Id: String?
    
    public static let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        formatter.timeStyle = .long
        formatter.locale = .current
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

and I am using it like this :

```
let date = ChatViewController.dateFromatter.date(from: dateString)
```

My date input in string is: “08-Jan-2023 at 8:57:10 PM GMT+5”

I just debug the whole code but I am not getting what is happening. When I debug it on physical device it works perfectly but when I run it on a simulator it is not working fine, i.e the debugger shows that in 'date' variables you have got nil.

Comment: One useful debugging too with DateFormatters is to call their `string(from:)` method and look at the format of the resulting string. When I pass the current date to your DateFormatter, I get back a date string of "Jan 8, 2023 at 4:06:47 PM EST".

Comment: If you are passing in date strings with a specific fixed format I suggest you st up your DateFormatter with a format string rather than trying to use the off-the-shelf dateStyle and timeStyle properties.

Comment: Based on my very limited testing, I would suggest that the local on your emulator is not based on `GMT+5`, which would make the `DateFormatter` unable to parse the `String`.  When I test the code I get `9 Jan 2023 at 8:08:00 am AEDT` - You need a "conversation" formatter which has a specific `dateFormat` `String` which matches your input format. Also, be aware that not all locales use uppercase for `am`/`pm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `dateStyle` and/or `timeStyle` when parsing a date string. Always use `dateFormat`. Styles can vary based on the user's locale and other settings on their device. It can also vary based on the user's language.

Since you need to parse a fixed format date string you need to provide a specific date format. You must also use a special locale on the date formatter since your fixed format date string is always in English.

```
public static let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy 'at' h:mm:ss a Z" // Might need O instead of Z at the end.
    return formatter
}()
```

Comment: you should set the locale before setting the dateFormat

Comment: @LeoDabus Does it really affect the result? I'll have try some tests but I've updated the answer just incase. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear, I was unable to advance for i guess 2-3 hrs, just got stuck in that problem, so Thank you very much !

Comment: @HangarRash Sir can you tell me how to decide the format on the basis of given date format ? like how do u know that there would be a 'Z' or '0' at the end ? Can you share a useful resource regarding this please ?

Comment: DateFormatter uses standard Unicode format specifiers. You can find these at http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: @HangarRash **"Once you've set "en_US_POSIX" as the locale of the date formatter, you can then set the date format string and the date formatter will behave consistently for all users"** [NSDateFormatter and Internet Dates](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html)

Answer (score -1):

How about this date formatter:

```
let customFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy' at 'h:mm:ss a ZZZZ"
    return formatter
}()
```

Comment: You need POSIX locale.

Comment: YYYY is wrong. It means yearForWeekOfYear

Comment: The time zone is also wrong anyway :)

Comment: @Sulthan DateFormatter is very forgiving when parsing timezones. Z, ZZZZ, O, all work for `GMT+5`. The timezone format specifier is far more critical when converting a Date to a String.

Comment: @Huzaifa Don't use this answer, there are really subtle problems here. Use the other one.

Comment: @Huzaifa This answer will only work about 51.5 weeks of the year and only with some device locales.

Comment: Note that I had some mistakes. I edited it and changed the format to use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`, and set the locale to "en_US_POSIX"